# How to get selection with ManyToMany relationship in the Play framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I have three models:

### Role

```
@Entity
public class Role extends Model {

    @Required
    public String machineryName;

    // ...
}
```

### User

```
public class User extends Model {

        // ...

    @ManyToOne
    public Role role;

        // ...

}
```

### Hall

```
@Entity
public class Hall extends Model {

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    public Set<User> waiters = new HashSet<User>();

    // ...

}
```

Now I want get all users with role "waiter" (machineryName) and linked with specific hall. Can you help me? Thanks.